# How to add ui-icon to my header panel dynamically?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I create my panel dynamically and i want to add icon like 'ui-icon-pencil' to my header panel dynamically too. I saw that it was possible to do with f:facet tag, but I don't know how to dynamically add this tag. A suggestion maybe?

I want this XHTML structure with java code:

```
<p:panel id="pnl">  
    <f:facet name="options">  
        <h:outputText value="Panel 1"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Edit" url="#" icon="ui-icon-pencil"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

And I need a click listener on my MenuItem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add facets to the component programmatically by putting them in the map as available by [`UIComponent#getFacets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getFacets%28%29).

So, the Java equivalent of this:

```html
<p:panel>
    <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="bar" /></f:facet>
</p:panel>
```

would be as follows:

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
UIOutput header = new HtmlOutputText();
header.setValue("bar");
panel.getFacets().put("header", header);
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for the answer, but when I replace UIoutput by MenuItem nothing appears. Is it possible with "panel.getfacet ()" to add a UIoutput and MenuItem in the same header?                 `MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.setIcon("ui-icon-pencil");
panel.getFacets().put("header", item);`

Comment: Please show the (working!) XHTML equivalent, then I will be able to tell how to create exactly that tree structure in Java.

Comment: That XHTML code does not work at all. I asked to post working! XHTML code. A `<f:facet>` cannot have multiple children. It can have only one child. You need a `<h:panelGroup>` around the `<h:outputText>` and `<p:menuItem>`. Surely you can now figure out how to create that programmatically? :) Keep in mind: if it's not possible with XHTML alone, then it's surely not possible programmatically either. Anything which is possible programmatically can also be done with XHTML alone.

Comment: I can not find how to create dynamically Panelgroup, I find only for PanelGrid. This could work with PanelGrid?

Comment: Just `new HtmlPanelGroup()`.

Comment: It works with several UIoutput, now I need to find the problem with the MenuItem. Thank you again, :).